# Let A and B be sets. Is $\lnot(A \setminus B) = B \setminus A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be sets. The complement of B with respect to A is defined as $A\setminus B$ = { $x \in A$ : $x \not\in B$}. What is the negation of $A\setminus B$? From the definition could it be { $x \not\in A$ : $x \in B$} = { $x \in B$ : $x \not\in A$} = $B \setminus A$? That is $\lnot(A\setminus B) = B \setminus A$.

Is above correct?

Comment: What is your definitions of $\neg$?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a common set $X$ then the negation $\neg A$ is $X\setminus A$. This notation comes from regarding the power set $PX$ as a Boolean algebra. Do you mean this?

Comment: It may help to consider $A$ and $B$ as both being subsets of a same universal set, $\Omega$ and consider complements with respect to that universal set.  $A\setminus B$ is equivalent then to $A\cap B^c$.  Assuming that by $\neg$ you mean complementation, we have that $(A\setminus B)^c = (A\cap B^c)^c = A^c\cup B$ is not the same thing as $B\setminus A = B\cap A^c$

Comment: $\lnot$ is the symbol for negation (of a statement). My apologies for the confusionI  did not ask my question properly as indicated in the answer below. I should have asked what is $\lnot (x \in (A \setminus B))$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$A\setminus B$ is not a statement. Did you mean the negation of $x \in A \setminus B$ ? It is:
$$
\neg (x \in A \setminus B) \equiv (x \notin A \vee (x \in A \wedge x \in B)),
$$
which is not
$$
(x \in B \setminus A) \equiv (x \in B \wedge x \notin A).
$$

By the way, it is better to use $\equiv$ than to use $=$ for logically equivalent statements. :)

Comment: Yes I meant the negation of $x \in A \setminus B$. Sorry about the confusion I did cause.